# Hive: parsing JSON

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am trying to get some values out of nested JSON for millions of rows (5 TB+ table). What is the most efficient way to do this?

Here is an example:

```
{"country":"US","page":227,"data":{"ad":{"impressions":{"s":10,"o":10}}}}
```

I need these values out of the above JSON:

```
Country        Page      impressions_s       impressions_o
---------      -----     -------------       --------------
US              2        10                  10
```

This is Hive's json_tuple function, I am not sure if this is the best function.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-getjsonobject

Answer (score 26):

You can use get_json_object:

```
 select get_json_object(fieldname, '$.country'), 
        get_json_object(fieldname, '$.data.ad.s') from ...
```

You will get better performance with json_tuple but I found a "how to" to get the values in json inside json;
To formating your table you can use something like this:

`from table t lateral view 
explode( split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(ln, ''$.data.ad.s'), '\\[|\\]', ''), ',' ) ) tb1 as s`

this code above will transform you "Array" in a column.

form more: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

I hope this help ...

Comment: UR a One hit wonder (nice answer, and then gone forever).  Feel free to come back and join in the fun here on SOF any time

Answer (score 8):

Here is what you can quickly try , I would suggest to use [Json-Ser-De](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde).

nano /tmp/hive-parsing-json.json

```
{"country":"US","page":227,"data":{"ad":{"impressions":{"s":10,"o":10}}}}
```

Create base table :

```
hive > CREATE TABLE hive_parsing_json_table ( json string );
```

Load json file to Table :

```
hive > LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH  '/tmp/hive-parsing-json.json' INTO TABLE hive_parsing_json_table;
```

Query the table :

```
hive >  select v1.Country, v1.Page, v4.impressions_s, v4.impressions_o 
from hive_parsing_json_table hpjp
     LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(hpjp.json, 'country', 'page', 'data') v1
     as Country, Page, data
     LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(v1.data, 'ad') v2
     as Ad
     LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(v2.Ad, 'impressions') v3
     as Impressions
     LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(v3.Impressions, 's' , 'o') v4
     as impressions_s,impressions_o;
```

Output :

```
v1.country  v1.page     v4.impressions_s    v4.impressions_o
US      227     10          10
```

Comment: For the record (I didn't see this documented), it appears if you combine a `LATERAL VIEW` statement with a join (e.g. `INNER JOIN`), the join must come before the lateral view (syntactically)

Answer (score 5):

Using hive native  `json-serde('org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe')` you can do this.. here are the steps

ADD JAR /path/to/hive-hcatalog-core.jar;

```
create a table as below 
 CREATE TABLE json_serde_nestedjson (
  country string,
  page int,
  data struct < ad: struct < impressions: struct < s:int, o:int  > > >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

then load data(stored in file)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/nested.json' INTO TABLE json_serde_nestedjson;
```

then get required data using

```
SELECT country, page, data.ad.impressions.s, data.ad.impressions.o 
FROM json_serde_nestedjson;
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a SerDe to parse your data in JSON is a better way for your case.

A tutorial on how to implement SerDe for parsing JSON can be found here

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/

You can use the following sample SerDe implementation as well

https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde